# iReport: display a static text conditionally

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to display a static text component conditionally.
To do that I have done:

```
<staticText>
<reportElement x="320" y="268" width="100" height="12" uuid="13df67df-2ccb-49bc-8a98-2ca9e3cc5f42">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[LEFT($F{idFacture},1).equals("A")]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
<text><![CDATA[Avoir sur facture :]]></text>
```

It works when I do a preview in Eclipse, but at runtime I am getting this exception :

> Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were
>   encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>   1. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type factureVente_1432127367493_934830
>                   value = LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_idFacture.getValue()),1).equals("A");
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=24$
>                           <-->
>   2. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type factureVente_1432127367493_934830
>                   value = LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_idFacture.getOldValue()),1).equals("A");
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=24$
>                           <-->
>   3. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type factureVente_1432127367493_934830
>                   value = LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_idFacture.getValue()),1).equals("A");
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=24$
>                           <-->

Does anyone know where I am wrong?

Comment: Why do you use left? Is it because you want the first letter?

Comment: yes, I used this because it was proposed in the list of String function in the designer. I replaced it by substring instead.

Comment: why don't you just do: $F{idFacture}.startsWith("A") ?

Comment: Because I didnt know this function :)

Comment: And did it work with that function? :p